# it didn't work to connect the android app to servlet page to passing data

Tags: android, servlets, android-intent, android-networking

i want to connect my android app to my servlet site ,, that i need to pass some data from the app to the url

Can anyone help me?

I have written this code to pass two parameters but it generates an exception:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://androidsaveitem.appspot.com/view");
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description+", "HAANAA"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id+", "11223"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams);
postMethod.setEntity(entity);
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
```

Comment: Those `+` signs in the form names look suspicious. Do they really belong there?

Comment: i can't post a pic >>>
how can i

Comment: 02-26 23:39:18.583: D/AndroidRuntime(331): Shutting down VM
02-26 23:39:18.583: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: 02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: 02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

Comment: 02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: 02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  ... 11 more
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: androidsaveitem.appspot.com

Comment: 02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)

Comment: 02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
02-26 23:39:18.633: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)

Comment: Comments are intented for comments, not for problem details. Please edit your question to update it with more problem detail.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are blocking the UI thread , and ANR Exception is raised since if your UI Thread is blocked for 5 second this exception will occur , to come over this issue you can use Thread or AsyncTask to do the job ,so your UI thread don't get blocked

example :

```
public myAsnyc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>{



protected void doInBackground(){

HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://androidsaveitem.appspot.com/view");
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description+", "HAANAA"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id+", "11223"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams);
postMethod.setEntity(entity);
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);



    }
protected void onPostExecute(){

    log.d("myApp", "success");
}

    }
```

and if you want to execute it 
make this call

```
new myAsnyc().execute();
```

if you want to update the UI elements use the `onPostExecute()` method and modify the generic type of the async task

UPDATE

execute the following code 
use this code

```
try {
      InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName("http://androidsaveitem.appspot.com/view");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

before you call the async task 
if the exception occur fine , re run the app second time it will run normally

Comment: it didn't work see this form the logCat view 

02-28 16:11:41.931: W/System.err(369): java.net.UnknownHostException: androidsaveitem.appspot.com
02-28 16:11:41.931: W/System.err(369):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
02-28 16:11:41.941: W/System.err(369):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
02-28 16:11:41.965: W/System.err(369):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)

Comment: 02-28 16:11:41.965: W/System.err(369):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
02-28 16:11:41.965: W/System.err(369):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-28 16:11:41.971: W/System.err(369):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)

Comment: use this code 

    try {
          InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(URLName);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: lsn call this code before you make any http request , if the exception still there , re run the app agin

Comment: but see this method its override not like you write above
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
}

Comment: So i make the following
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){ 
try {
    doInBackground();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}

Comment: btw >> i make the permission that you told me to get it in the manifast file

Comment: and i get this code 
 try { InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(URLName); } catch (UnknownHostException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
BEFORE this statement
 
 new MyAsnyc().execute();

Comment: unable to execute dex: JAva heap space
Java heap space

Comment: it's cant launch the activity

Comment: Nammari >>>
i execute it twice but still the same exception appear 
java.net.UnknownHostException: androidsaveitem.appspot.com 02-28 16:11:41.931: W/System.err(369): at

Comment: just the exception is my problem now

Comment: do you have a device ? or you run your app on the emulator